# How to use senthamizh fonts SMZTH (tamil language)?

Tags: unicode, keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

How to use senthamizh fonts in word 2016, the font layout not in your keyman desktop, how to use the font??? Please help ... The senthamizh font (SMZTH )  font is not unicode , how to use it??

Answer (score 0):

**Install keyman Tamil Software to type words in Tamil**